# multiplications shape in keras (?,15,?,196)

Tags: python, keras

I have a tensor of (? , 15 ,512) now i want to multiply it with (512 , 196)
why is the result shape is (? ,15 ,? , 196)
it should be (? , 15 ,196 )

```
V = Input(shape=(512,196))
Qw = (?,15,512)

Wb_intialization =  np.random.randn(512, 512).astype(np.float32) * 
np.sqrt(2.0/(512))

def fun(x):
x=np.array(x)
Wb = K.variable(Wb_intialization)
return  K.dot(Wb,V)
C =  Lambda(fun)(Qw)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two input tensors don't have the shapes you think they have.

According to the code sample, the shape of `Wb` is in fact `(512, 512)`. However, by the title of your question I believe you've actually intended to initialize `Wb` as follows:

```
Wb_intialization =  np.random.randn(15, 512).astype(np.float32) * np.sqrt(2.0/(512))
```

(that is, `(15, 512)` instead of `(512, 512)`).

Hence, the `Wb` tensor ends up with the shape `(?, 15, 512)`.

The shape of the `V` tensor is `(?, 512, 196)` (and not `(512, 196)`).

Therefore, the shape of the tensor resulting from multiplying `Wb` and `V` is `(?, 15, ?, 196)`.

The reason the output shape is `(?, 15, ?, 196)` is because the "common" `512` dimension of the two input tensors (`(?, 15, 512)` and `(?, 512, 196)`) serves as the product axis. Hence, only the 512 dimension is absent from the result and the other three surrounding dimensions remain.

Comment: so How to obtain the correct matrix multiplication of shape (? ,15,196) plz

Comment: @SoadSaleh, if you replace `K.dot(Wb, V)` with `K.dot(Wb, V[0, :, :])` you'll get the shape `(?, 15, 196)` but make sure that this is indeed what you're trying to achieve.